# I'm having trouble retrieving a salt from a mysql database using mysql.data. (c#)

Tags: c#, mysql, salt

I am creating a chat program, and I am using the mysql database to handle the log in information for all of the users. The login is fairly simple. The password that is in the database is SHA256 hashed with a salt at the end. I need to retrieve the salt from the database and hash it with the entered password to see if it matches the one in the database, and if it does, the user will be logged in. But I am having troubles retrieving the salt. One example of a salt that I am trying to retrieve is:

> **q‘³SÁ(–¤Lí˜ÕEÁÞf-]'›š²ìs®§ ­”**

. All I can successfully retrieve is this:

> **q‘³SÁ(–¤Lí˜ÕEÁ**

Here is my code for retrieving the salt:

```html
private void GetSalt()
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(GlobalData.MySQLConnectionString);
                MySqlCommand saltQuery = conn.CreateCommand();
                saltQuery.CommandText = "SELECT salt FROM users WHERE email = @email";
                saltQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", this._enteredEmail);
                conn.Open();
                MySqlDataReader saltReader = saltQuery.ExecuteReader();
                while (saltReader.Read())
                {
                    this._salt = saltReader.GetString("salt");
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Any idea why I can't retrieve the full salt?

P.S.-> All the user information is created through a website and hashed using PHP. I don't know if that is needed information or not.

Comment: If you are storing the salt as a string (improperly), maybe it contains nulls or EOF characters that are messing things up.   You may need to ASCII encode and decode it.   What are you storing it as?

Comment: @SteveWellens I'm storing it as a varchar

Comment: Is the full salt getting stored in the database? If you look at the entry in either PHP myAdmin or MySQL Workbench, is the full salt there? Is `n` in `varchar(n)` sufficiently large to hold the generated salt?

Comment: @JRLambert Yes, the full salt is in the database. Each salt has a possibility of being a maximum of 32 characters, and I have that set in the database also

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the [BCrypt.Net](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/) library, not only does it provide an appropriate algorithm for password hashing, it also handles the generation of a safe salt. Because the salt will be included in the resulting hash-value, there is no need for a separate field in the database.

Fast hash algorithms like MD5, SHA-1 or even SHA-256 are **not** good choices to hash passwords, because they are way too fast and therefore can be brute-forced too easily. Instead one should use a slow key-derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2 with a cost factor.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
string hashToStoreInDb = BCrypt.HashPassword(password);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from existingHashFromDb.
bool isPasswordCorrect = BCrypt.Verify(password, existingHashFromDb);
```